# How to select randomly from array exluding one value?

Tags: php, arrays

With the holidays slowly nearing, It's time to pick straws again. We always pick a piece of paper from a box containing everbody's name. However, this year I wanted to solve the issue of picking your own name from the box by using PHP.

I've got an array with names ex:

```
$names = [
    'John',
    'Jane',
    'Joe',
    'Matt',
    'Steve',
    'Anne',
    'Karin'
];
```

For each of these names, I wanna pick 4 random names, so that at the end every person has 4 names for which they will have to buy a present.

#### The issue

Well, I'm stuck. I've thought of a million ways on how to do this but I just can't come up with anything.

#### What I've tried so far

- Using a foreach
- Using `array_rand()`
- Shifting the array

The problem with these is that a person shouldn't be picking their own name and that everyone should be picked an even amount of times (4).

#### Update

Some great answers already posted. I'm not exactly sure though if this is fair for everyone. Everyone should at the end get 4 presents from 4 different persons.

I was thinking of adding each name to the `$names` array 4 times and then applying one of your answers. Am I on the right track with this?

#### Update 2

What I've tried now:

```
function select_rand($array, $exclude_array) {
    $diff = array_diff($array, $exclude_array);
    return $diff[array_rand($diff, 1)];
}

$workArray = [
    '0' => $names,
    '1' => $names,
    '2' => $names,
    '3' => $names,
];

foreach ($names as $k => $name) {
    $i = 0;
    $new[$name] = array();
    while ($i < 4) {
        $value = select_rand($workArray[$i], array_merge($new[$name], array($name)));
        if (($key = array_search($value, $workArray[$i])) !== false) {
            unset($workArray[$i][$key]);
        }
        $new[$name][] = $value;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This works only in a few caes.

Comment: `array_rand()`, `array_diff()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use shuffle, and array_slice for this job:

```
$names = [
    'John',
    'Jane',
    'Joe',
    'Matt',
    'Steve',
    'Anne',
    'Karin'
];

foreach ($names as $name) {
   // working array
   $working = $names;
   // remove current name from array,no one wants to buy presents for him/her self..
   unset($working[$name]);
   shuffle($working);
   $people = array_slice($working, 0, 4);
   echo $name . ' has to buy presents for:';
   var_dump($people);
}
```

Comment: This looks great, and comes really close. But each person gets assigned 4 names. These 4 have to be unique. Though the names array contains 30 persons instead of 7 if this is usefull.

Answer (score 1):

This can help -

```
function select_rand($array, $exclude_array) {
    $diff= array_diff($array, $exclude_array);
    return $diff[array_rand($diff, 1)];
}

$names = array(
    'John',
    'Jane',
    'Joe',
    'Matt',
    'Steve',
    'Anne',
    'Karin'
);
foreach($names as $name)
{
    $i = 0;
    $new[$name] = array();
    while($i < 4) {
        $new[$name][] = select_rand($names, array_merge($new[$name], array($name)));
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This will generate a new `array` for each `name` (as `key`) in that array containing **4 unique names**.

[FIDDLE](https://eval.in/453313)

**Update**

```
$new[$name][] = select_rand($names, array_merge($new[$name], array($name, 'Karin')));
```

Comment: Works great but how will this prevent for example Karin from getting a present from everyone?

Comment: @Peter Check the update. Just add **Karin** to the array to be excluded. :)

Comment: Adding Karin won't solve my issue will it? The others would then still be able to get more than 4 presents.

Comment: How many gifts one should get then? What should be the limit for each name?

Comment: Each Person should get 4 names. But everyone should only be able to get picked 4 times.

Comment: Then add a loop in that function to check how many times a name is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom function like as

```
$names = [
    'John',
    'Jane',
    'Joe',
    'Matt',
    'Steve',
    'Anne',
    'Karin'
];

$my_name = "John";
$limit = 4;

function get_name($arr,$your_name,$limit){
    $key = array_flip($arr)[$your_name];
    unset($arr[$key]);
    $rand_keys = array_rand($arr,$limit);
    $result = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($rand_keys));
    return implode(',',$result);
}

echo get_name($names,$my_name,$limit);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/453123)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to have an even distribution of presents per person, you need to have more control over it. Anyhow, in this code I keep track of number of presents per person. I initialise it with zero: `$presents = array_fill_keys($names, 0);`. Then after each selection I updated this number `$presents[$key]++;`.

```
<?php
$names = array(
    'John',
    'Jane',
    'Joe',
    'Matt',
    'Steve',
    'Anne',
    'Karin'
);

$presents_number = 4;
// initialization 
$presents = array_fill_keys($names, 0);
$names_names = array();
foreach ($names as $i => $picker)  {
    $box = $names;
    unset($box[$i]);
    
    // filter out the people with maximum presents:
    foreach ($presents as $key => $number) {
        if (($presents[$key] > $presents_number-1) && in_array($key, $box)) {
            $box = array_diff($box, array($key));
        }
    }

    // shuffle the box and select 4 top
    shuffle($box);
    $selection = array_slice($box, 0, $presents_number);
    foreach ($selection as $key) {
        $presents[$key]++;
    }
    $names_names[$picker] = $selection;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($names_names);
echo "</pre>";
```

There can be more to be considered mathematically. Specially since loops can happen, this algorithm can go wrong. I haven't spend time on it. But as an example of 3 people and one present per person. (A, B, C)

correct answer:

> A => {B}
>
> B => {C}
>
> C => {A}

wrong answer:

> A => {B}
>
> B => {A}
>
> C => {}

Basically, the perfect algorithm should to avoid these wrong answers. Maybe later I fixed the problem as an update for this post.